# Ansible error Received exit status from master

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

I've written a seemingly simple ansible task to connect to an ec2 instance and configure the timezone. The ansible task is as follows

```
---
- name: Set Time Zone variables
  copy: content='Etc/UTC' dest=/etc/timezone owner=root group=root mode=0644 backup=yes
```

and the command used to run the task is

```
ansible-playbook nectar.yml  --extra-vars "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python env=DEVELOPMENT" -vvvv
```

my ansible.cfg looks like

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

But I keep getting the error message

```
<54.237.211.85> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<54.237.211.85> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="./nectar-web.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ubuntu -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/Users/reagan/.ansible/cp/5113bdcc33 -tt 54.237.211.85 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/local/bin/python /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522003225.61-27057727697133/command.py; rm -rf "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522003225.61-27057727697133/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<54.237.211.85> (0, '/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/python: not found\r\n', 'OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 98004\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\nShared connection to 54.237.211.85 closed.\r\n')
fatal: [54.237.211.85]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 98004\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\nShared connection to 54.237.211.85 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc":
```

Any ideas on why ansible keeps getting this error when reusing the master connection?

Comment: You are trying to execute `/usr/local/bin/python` on a remote host and the error message tells you, it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

Have done something like this on top of playbook, if I've to run something on vanilla ubuntu AMI.

````
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: someuser
  gather_facts: False
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install python for Ansible
      raw: test -f /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)
      become: true
```

- setup: # aka gather_facts
````

Answer (score -2):

Try to install on target machine python.
I have same error:

```
dworker-01 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to dworker-01 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/python: not found\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 127
}
```

target machine:
`apt-get update && apt-get install python`
after that all ok.